# Actionscript CameraRoll delete Images

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, photos

I am currently using Actionscript 3.0 with Animate CC.  I have CameraRoll working in Actionscript perfectly.   I can browse and add photos from the Gallery.  I have a need to delete photos from the Gallery using either the CameraRoll class or the File class.

After a thorough search on the net and Adobe API pages it doesn't appear that CameraRoll allows either deletion of photos once it browses or allows the native delete gallery function to be executed.

Is there a method in the CameraRoll class that I missed or should I look at using the File class to browse the image directories?  If the latter then does anyone have a good example on how to do this were the images are displayed in the gallery format?  Keep in mind that all images and connections should remain local to the phone.  There can be no internet access where a web interface could be used of any kind.  Also the local native image store is the source of all images.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I believe you arent able to delete an image using CameraRoll. CameraRoll API allow access to browse image only. I dont think your second option using File class would work either because your application will be running in its own sandbox. Your best option is to save the image in your application storage and then retrieve and delete it from there.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  I did find a way to do it.  I am testing it now.  So far it works but I am looking for a more elegant solution before I post the answer.  Thanks again though.

Comment: Ok here is the problem. When I run the delete() method in the File class against files created on my SDCARD with my script it works.  When I run the delete() method against files on my SDCARD created by normal phone operations like camera, downloads, screenshots or others then I get a 3012 error saying I cant delete the file.  That happens with moveToTrash or moveTo as well.    Anyone else know of a fix for this?